# Merging a branch with commits to a new branch without conflit, losing work

Tags: git, merge

I was working on a branch and after unsuccesful attemps I created a new branch from the branch I was working.

Once there I succeded to do what I tried in the other branch.

I would like to know if there is a command of merging the "old" branch to the new without erasing the work of the new branch, keeping the old commits from the old branch, without conflict ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git merge`.

Eg.

Original branch: `master`
New branch: `some_branch`

Now Switch to `some_branch` and try `git merge master`

This will try to merge `master` onto `some_branch`

Now if you don't have any conflict, git will auto merge the branch.

Git has many merge strategies like `recursive, ours, their`

If you end up have conflict, you have to manually resolve the issues and merge it.

I would suggest you to create one more branch from master say `new_merge_branch` and switch to it.

Now try merging `some_branch` onto `new_merge_branch` with the help of

`git merge some_branch`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try it. I thought git rebase was the solution but what does it do git rebase?

Comment: I actually prefer `git rebase` than `git merge`. `git rebase` usually takes commits 1 by 1 from source branch and tries to apply on the current branch.

Comment: So git rebase could do the work? I can create a new branch and rebase/merge my two branches in it for test?

Comment: Yes, you may try `git rebase` with branch from which you want to apply commits

Comment: Ok will try that